# PHP global variable not visible inside nested functions

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
   $a = 1;
   function_one();
?>

<?php
   function_one() {
      global $a;
      function_two();
?>

<?php
   function_two() {
      function_three();
   }
?>

<?php
   function_three() {
      echo ($a);
   }
?>
```

Inside `function_three()`, the variable `$a` is not accessible although I have declared it as global in `function_one()`, which calls `function_two()` which in turn calls `function_three()`. Why is that so? I had to declare once more on `global $a` inside `function_three()` to get `$a`'s value.

Is there a way to make `$a` accessible inside `function_three()` without declaring `global` once more? Is there another way to make outer variables visible inside a `function` without using `global` and passing in the function's parameters?

Comment: The keyword `global` does not define a variable into the global scope but it is to import a global into the local scope and reference it - Also don't use global variables, start looking into `OOP`

Comment: What one function does does not influence the scope of another function.

Comment: @DarkBee If I can't use `OOP` because of regulations in my place, what other alternatives can I use besides `global`? I don't really want to use it either.

Comment: @deceze I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

```
   <?php          
       $GLOBALS['a'] = 1;

       function function_one() {    
          function_two();
       }

        function function_two() {
          function_three();
       }

        function function_three() {
          echo $GLOBALS['a'];
       }

       function_one();
    ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
```

OR just import the global into local scope like @DarkBee mentioned:

```
<?php

   $a = 1;

   function function_one() {    
      function_two();
   }

    function function_two() {
      function_three();
   }

    function function_three() {
        global $a;
        echo $a;
   }

   function_one();
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
```

Comment: I see. Thank you. Is there another way to do it besides using this?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer I would recommend the `$GLOBALS` super variable over the other.

Comment: Thank you. I'll opt for the second one. What's the other alternative besides using `global` to give visibility to inner functions? Passing parameters, using superglobals. What else?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer this is too broad, like you mentioned, passing params, using superglobals, accessing globals by declarations, using classes. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `global` if possible. I can't use OOP here as I'm not allowed to. Is the only other way by passing parameters?